# The proper way of using Sequelize to define a exist table Model

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

i have read the Sequelize doc but didn't find a clear explanation on defining the model for exsist table.

I have a table arleady in my db and called ps_product with 3 columns, name(varchar), barcode(varchar), product_id(primarykey)

but when i wanna define the model of this table i tried

```
var product = sequelize.define('product',{  
    name:Sequelize.STRING,
    barcode:Sequelize.STRING
});
```

But in this way if i call seuqelize.sync() will create a table for me which is not what i want, 
i only wanna mapping the model relation to my ps_product table.
so my questions are:

1. how can i define a model on an exist table? at least where do i need to put my table name?
2. From the define methods, i can define as much property as i want event it is not fully match the table columns right?

I think the doc didn't fully cover these basic concept it would be appreciate if someone could explain bit more thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking into a tool like sequelize-auto: 
[sequelize-auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-auto)

This can generate models for you from a database table.

Use it like this:

```
sequelize-auto -h <host> -d <database> -u <user> -x [password] -p [port]  --dialect [dialect] -c [/path/to/config] -o [/path/to/models] -t [tableName] -C
```

Example:

```
sequelize-auto -o "./models" -d sequelize_auto_test -h localhost -u my_username -p 5432 -x my_password -e postgres
```